# How to integrate googletest to stm32 cmake project

Tags: cmake, stm32, googletest

I made my project, which I created with STM32 cubeIDE, compilable with Cmake, but I had problems with googletest integration.

The file structure of the entire project is as follows;

[image]

[Project Link](https://github.com/ugurkebir/stm32f4Cmake)

I created the project and test folders as two different cmake projects. I don't have any problems compiling the project, but I could not establish a healthy connection between the test and the project. Because when compiling the test I get an error.

When I add the source and header files related to the Project to the CmakeList.txt in the test, I get an error in the project's variables and type definitions.

The cmake commands I used in the test file directory are as follows;

```
$cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<path_to_Project/cmake/gcc-arm-none-eabi.cmake> -S<path_to_Test> -B<path_to_Test/build/Debug> -G Ninja

$cmake --build <path_to_Test/build/Debug> -j 8
```

Errors;

[image: Errors]

Do you have any advice to integrate googletest into existing cmake project?

Comment: "I tried downloading googletest repository, ExternalProject and FetchContent methods but got errors in all of them." - Do you mean that **none** of approaches with cloning the repo, `ExternalProject`, or `FetchContent` works for you and you ask us to suggest **something else**? As far as I could tell, any of these approaches **should work**. Or do you mean that you probably uses these approaches (or one of them) is a wrong way, and you ask us about the **correct way**? In that case you need to describe what **exactly** have you **tried**, and the **exact errors** (or other problems) you got.

Comment: And no, we don't need a **link** to your project. We need to see all relevant code in the **question post** itself. Preferably in form of [mcve].

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Answer of question is "Or do you mean that you probably uses these approaches (or one of them) is a wrong way, and you ask us about the correct way?". The reason I gave the repository link is to show the file structure(or file tree) and CmakeList.txt files.  My problem is not in any code snippet. It's about the structure of the project and the CmakeList.txt files.

Comment: See [this link](https://kleinembedded.com/unit-testing-in-stm32cubeide-with-googletest/) and also read the comment part of the link. Hope it will help.

Comment: "My problem is not in any code snippet. It's about the structure of the project and the CmakeList.txt files." - While CMake allows to create a project with "nice" structure, a project's structure rarely affects on whether some coding *approach* will be correct or not. All you need is to correctly specify target names, file paths, properties.

Comment: Compiler errors in a "correct" source or header usually mean that you incorrectly specify parameters for the compilation: include directories, defines, etc. E.g. by looking to your `Project/CMakeLists.txt` I see that it specifies much more compiler parameters that your `Test/CMakeLists.txt`. This difference could easily be a reason of the problems you got. (And this reason is absolutely not related to the usage of googletest, since your test includes none headers from the Project.)

Comment: I didn't include any headers from the project in the test code, because I'm getting a lot of compilation error even without including it anyway. I totally agree with you about compile parameters. The problem is that I cannot set the toolchain setting and compile parameters correctly in Test/CmakeList.txt. I asked the question to find out how to do the correct configuration in Test/CmakeList.txt.

Comment: There is one more thing I want to add. The project part already has a working cmake configuration. All the problems started after I tried to add Test to the Project which was working fine. The template gtest documents show test codes with simple projects compiled in gcc. But what I need is to add a Test to the cmake project configured for stm32 (arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain and compile parameters), where I can write the test codes of the functions of the stm32 project.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you plan to run the unit tests on the target device (MCU), you cannot and should not include any microcontroller-specific code, such as HAL.

Here are the some approaches for unit testing embedded projects:

- Separate testable code into libraries. This code should not rely on any hardware-specific stuff. Then you can unit-test the library independently.
- If you need to test code that relies on peripherals, you need to abstract the peripherals and create mocks for use in unit tests. This is quite a lot of work to implement and maintain.

Not every piece of code is meant to be unit tested, do some more research to get a better idea of different test types.

**Update**

So the goal is to run the tests on the target. In that case, I would recommend choosing a different testing framework, as gtest is probably too big to fit on a MCU, even if you could somehow compile it.

I know someone who used [cmocka](https://cmocka.org/) for this purpose. The flow would be something like this:

1. Set-up your code to output the test results through, for example, a serial port.
2. Compile your tests for the MCU.
3. Upload the test firmware to the MCU.
4. Run the tests and examine the output.

Comment: Hi @Armandas, thanks for useful information about unit testing on embedded project. As you said in your first sentence, I want to run my unit tests on the MCU. Mocking might be a good option, but as a first step, I thought unit testing running on the MCU would be more applicable.

Actually, I succeeded my goal by using two different platforms. One of them is platformio, which is available as VS Code extention, and the other is the use of Unity with CubeIDE. However, I still haven't been able to integrate gtest into my ready-made project, which I compiled with Cmake.

Comment: @Purgoufr I have updated my answer to include target-based testing.